# How to use React Native Reanimated with EAS builds?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated, eas, react-native-pdf

I have created an identical app twice, following the installations intstructions of the react-native-reanimated documentation https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/getting-started/#installation.

Once with Expo go, where it also functions normally and the second one with development builds ( started with: `npx expo start --dev-client` ). But with development builds an error occurs:

> ERROR  Error: [Reanimated] The native part of Reanimated doesn't seem
> to be initialized. This could be caused by
>
> - not rebuilding the app after installing or upgrading Reanimated
> - trying to run Reanimated on an unsupported platform
> - running in a brownfield app without manually initializing the native library, js engine: hermes  ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main"
>   has not been registered. This can happen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart  it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

As far as I know, the React Native Reanimated Documentation does not provide additional information regarding EAS builds.

Does anybody know how to use the react-native-reanimated library with development builds? I need development builds, since I have another library that can only function with it (react-native-pdf).

Comment: My Error was that i did not run these commands after installing the library: 

"npm install -g eas-cli",
"eas build -p android --profile development"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and successfully resolved it by following these steps:

1. Begin by restarting your development server and clearing the bundler cache with this command: npx expo start --clear.
2. Remove all npm packages and the package-lock.json file.
3. Delete all build files located in the iOS directory.
4. Remove your project from the Expo dashboard and set up a new one.
5. Remember to update your eas.json file with the new project ID.
6. Finally, rebuild your project using Expo.
   If you developed on real device, remember to uninstall the app and re-install the new one.

I hope this solution proves helpful for you as well.